# how to eliminate another actionColumn in yii2?

Tags: gridview, view, yii2, action

I'm new to yii2,i want to make view for student data,in this picture i want to eliminate delete and edit icon,how can i eliminate this icon?[This is my web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBV1F.jpg)

This is my source code for this index view

```
    GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'nis',
        'nama_siswa',
        'jenis_kelamin',
         'telp',
         [
           ...],
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],

    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {update}'],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `template` property of ActionColumn as

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'nis',
        'nama_siswa',
        'jenis_kelamin',
         'telp',
         [
           ...],
      [
       'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
       'template' => '{view}'
     ],

    ],
]); ?>
```