# How to remove glyphicon glyphicon-pencil or edit,view,delete button from gridview page in yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2, datacolumn

[image]

How to remove glyph-icon-pencil and glyph-icon trash from  particular page in yii2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to eliminate another actionColumn in yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755949/how-to-eliminate-another-actioncolumn-in-yii2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with template in actionColumn

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        .........
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view} {delete}',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: I forgot the location of that file. Where is that file located?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using Yii 1.* then this would be beneficial.

Open this file: framework/zii/widgets/grid/CButtonColumn.php

**Remove** *{delete}* and make **$template** like this:

```
public $template='{view} {update}';
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a line below to all view data as-

```
// ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
```

I just commented this and got working for me.